# Как проверить у файла наличие защиты?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

При скачивании файла с интернета он маркируется для защиты таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью своего приложения отслеживать файлы с такой пометкой защиты?
Например при перетаскивании файла на приложение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужно просто разблокировать файл в случае, если он заблокирован.

Официальный путь — вызовите Powershell-cmdlet [`Unblock-File`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-5.1). Для этого установите nuget-пакет `System.Management.Automation`, и воспользуйтесь таким кодом:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("Unblock-File", true);
    ps.AddParameter("LiteralPath", fullPath);
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

---

Альтернативный путь — можно воспользоваться знанием о том, что в текущих версиях Windows данные о заблокированном файле содержатся в альтернативном потоке данных NTFS под названием Zone.Identifier, и убрать его через P/Invoke ([код одолжен на en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6375599/276994)):

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFile(string name );

public bool Unblock(string fileName) {
    return DeleteFile(fileName + ":Zone.Identifier");
}
```

---

Окей, если вам и правда нужно лишь *проверить*, есть ли защита, придётся поработать с COM-объектами. За блокировку отвечает COM-объект [PersistentZoneIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029(v=vs.85).aspx). Код одолжен [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777944/276994) и [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131104-00/?p=2753), и адаптирован.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

static class BlockChecker
{
    public static bool IsBlocked(string path)
    {
        object persistZoneId = Activator.CreateInstance(
            Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse(CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier)));
        var zoneIdentifier = (IZoneIdentifier)persistZoneId;
        var persistFile = (IPersistFile)persistZoneId;
        try
        {
            persistFile.Load(path, 0); // STGM_READ
            var id = zoneIdentifier.GetId();
            return id == URLZONE.URLZONE_INTERNET || id == URLZONE.URLZONE_UNTRUSTED;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (persistZoneId != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(persistZoneId);
        }
    }

    const string CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier = "0968e258-16c7-4dba-aa86-462dd61e31a3";
    const string IID_IZoneIdentifier = "cd45f185-1b21-48e2-967b-ead743a8914e";

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid(IID_IZoneIdentifier)]
    public interface IZoneIdentifier
    {
        URLZONE GetId();
        void SetId(URLZONE zone);
        void Remove();
    }

    public enum URLZONE : uint
    {
        URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0,
        URLZONE_INTRANET = 1,
        URLZONE_TRUSTED = 2,
        URLZONE_INTERNET = 3,
        URLZONE_UNTRUSTED = 4,
    }
}
```

Пользоваться очевидным образом: `BlockChecker.IsBlocked(fullPath)`.

Если файла не существует, то будет возвращено `true`, так что проверяйте самостоятельно.

Если что, вы можете и удалить блокировку при помощи

```
zoneIdentifier.Remove();
persistFile.Save(path, true);
```

Comment: Автор, вроде, просит не снять блок, а проверить его наличие

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Хм. И правда. Сейчас посмотрю, как её просто проверить.

Comment: Нужно только узнать защищен ли файл системой, нет необходимости снимать защиту. Это нужно для того, чтобы через приложение не запускались остальные файлы без защиты (установленные программы и т.д.).

Comment: @VladD, проверить существование `fileName + ":Zone.Identifier"`?

Comment: Подскажите, как можно привязать код к условию? Например, если защита на файл есть, то вывести сообщение: `MessageBox.Show("Файл защищен");`

Comment: @Vitokhv: Дописал ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Грязновато как-то. А вдруг там разрешённая зона, а мы доложим, что запрещённая?

Comment: Не для проверки, но для сброса признака - можно переписать файл. Всмысле, обычный `File.WriteAllBytes` сбросит признак =)

Comment: @Monk: Ну это тоже не очень: у нас может не быть прав на создание нового файла, плюс диск может быть полным, плюс меняется дата модификации. Ну и опять-таки это неофициальный путь. Плюс если файл реально огромный, это будет долго.

Comment: Добавил отдельный класс, вроде бы определяет с помощью строки: `else if (args.Any() && BlockChecker.IsBlocked(args[0]) == true)`