# Как открыть файл с помощью команды приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, реестр

Как открыть файл, чтобы он запускался через приложение? При условии, что реестр использует обязательный путь к приложению:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит в том, чтобы через приложение "А" передать параметры запуска `"%1" %*` любому файлу, который принудительно станет запускаться через это приложение "А".

Допустим, мы переносим файл на приложение, или запускаем его двойным кликом по файлу, приложение получает от файла аргументы в виде пути к файлу, если первое условие пропускается, файл "В" должен получить от приложения "А" аргументы запуска `"%1" %*`и запуститься.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Any() && BlockChecker.IsBlocked(args[0]) == true)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else if (args.Any())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo((args[0]), @"%1 %*");
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start(psi);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Вышеупомянутый код работает, но не может принимать аргументы от ярлыков, все еще есть ошибки при запуске программ (Discord) и (браузер Opera) т.к. они используют ярлык с аргументами запуска: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe`

Эта проблема относится ко всем ярлыкам или программам с параметрами запуска...

Подробнее о классе BlockChecker.cs: [#url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765571)

Comment: Если честно, нихрена не понятно.

Comment: Попробую еще раз, нужно чтобы приложение пропускало через себя запуск файла. По умолчанию реестр использует для запуска `exefile` аргументы `"%1" %*` нужно передать эти аргументы файлу, через приложение, чтобы файл запустился свободно, как будто приложению он не нужен. На данный момент, запуск происходит через путь к файлу `psi.FileName = (args[0]);` думаю это и мешает файлам запуститься полноценно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из тех случаев, когда ответ - "Пожалуйста, не делайте этого". Изменять ассоциации для EXE файлов - плохая идея.

Во-первых, это работает только для запуска путем открытия файла в проводнике. Это не распространяется на другие способы запуска программ - через ярлыки, функцию "Открыть с помощью", командную строку и т.п. Во-вторых, если что-то пойдет не так, пользователь не сможет открыть в проводнике ни один EXE-файл.

Также антивирусные программы могут воспринимать это как подозрительное поведение (так как некоторые вирусы используют эту методику) и заблокировать или удалить вашу программу.

---

Не понимаю также, зачем вам устанавливать свойство `RedirectStandardOutput`. Оно создает связь между дочерним и родительским процессами, которая может привести к возможным проблемам. Если приложение консольное, текст в консоли не будет выводиться.

Далее, передача в `ProcessStartInfo` строки `"%1 %*"` не имеет никакого смысла. Запись с процентами - это не настоящие параметры, а подстановочный знак, который проводник меняет на конкретные параметры при вызове ассоциированной программы (%* означает все параметры). Вероятно, больший смысл бы имело в реестр запихать команду `"MyApp.exe %*"`, чтобы вашей программе передавались все параметры, и потом соответственно, все содержимое args объединять и передавать в `ProcessStartInfo`. Но все равно, я не думаю, что это рабочий способ.

---

Если вам нужно отслеживать запуск программ и выполнять определенные действия, можно найти лучшее решение:

- Отслеживание события WMI [InstanceCreationEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394649(v=vs.85).aspx) для Win32_Process (уведомление приходит с задержкой минимум в 1 секунду).
- Использование библиотеки [TraceEvent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2013/03/09/using-traceevent-to-mine-information-in-os-registered-etw-providers/) (также имеется некоторая задержка уведомления)
- Разработать драйвер уровня ядра, и использовать функцию [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951(v=vs.85).aspx) для подписки на глобальное событие создания процесса
- Перехват функции kernel32.dll CreateProcessInternal, как предлагает ответ пользователя Максим.

Пример для отслеживания запуска процесса через WMI:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

public class EventWatcherPolling
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create event query to be notified within 1 second of 
        // a change in a service
        WqlEventQuery query =
            new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent",
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");

        // Initialize an event watcher and subscribe to events 
        // that match this query
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher =
            new ManagementEventWatcher();
        watcher.Query = query;        

        // Block until the next event occurs         
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Waiting for events...");

        ManagementBaseObject e;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();

                //Display information from the event
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Process {0} has been created, path is: {1}, id is {2}",
                    ((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["Name"],
                    ((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["ExecutablePath"],
                    ((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["ProcessId"]
                    );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }        

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описание. Хотел, что-то вроде этого: https://habrahabr.ru/post/335736/ но для расширения *.exe (думаю выбор каталогов помог бы избавиться от необходимости проверять все файлы).

Comment: Кстати, на ярлыки подмена `exefile\shell\open\command` тоже подействует. А меню "Открыть с помощью"  для `*.exe` не наблюдается. Более того, это будет работать с любыми программами, использующими ShellExecute[Ex] для запуска процессов. Это даже на UAC подействует, если `open` заменить на `runas`. Но да, поэтому здесь надо быть очень аккуратным.

Comment: @diversenok _"А меню "Открыть с помощью" для *.exe не наблюдается"_ - я имел в виду меню Открыть с помощью для других файлов, не exe. Оно тоже может использоваться для запуска программ.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, действительно, это сработает. Открытие файлов также происходит через ShellExecute, но сама программа будет запущена CreateProcess'ом, а на него эти настройки не повлияют.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, вы хотите что бы все `EXE` файлы выполнялись через ваш exe. Проверьте что находиться в `args[1]`, думаю параметры должны быть там. Например:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Any() && BlockChecker.IsBlocked(args[0]) == true)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else if (args.Any())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo((args[0]), args[1]);
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start(psi);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

P.S.: Это неверный способ выполнять какие либо действия перед запуском любого `exe`. Есть стандартные способы - хуки и внедрение dll.

Comment: Если передается ярлык, то передастся именно ярлык, но не параметры запуска ярлыка как 2й параметр.

Comment: В таком случае, нужно доставать из свойств ярлыка эти параметры. В любом случае, это неверный способ выполнять какие либо действия перед запуском любого `exe`. Есть стандартные способы - хуки и внедрение dll.