# Запуск и работы формы только при запущенном процессе

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно сделать так, чтобы форма запускалась и работала только при запущенном процессе?

Я пробовал так:

```
while (1 > 0) {
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("gameWoT");
    if (pname.Length == 0) {
        f3.Close();
    }
    else {
        f3.Show();
    }                   
}
```

Это, в принципе, частично работает, но цикл - не вариант.

Можно ли как-то иначе это реализовать? Чтобы именно форма работала после запуска процесса, а если процесс завершен, то форма закрывалась?

Comment: Как я понял тебе требуется отображать форму f3 при запущенном процессе gameWot, при его завершении закрывать форму, так?

Comment: Вроде как единственный юзермодный способ получать нотификации о создании процессов - через WMI (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @Tivyram да именно так

Comment: Грамотнее, конечно, сделать хук. Но у нас, как бы, завершение процесса и это происходит без каких либо событий в системе. Только если проверять в цикле факт существования процесса по имени... Но можно пойти и обходными путями. Есть ли у этого процесса окно?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Требуется же обнаружить не событие создания процесса, а факт его завершения.

Comment: @D .Stark да есть это игра пишем модуль для защиты процесса

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  Желательно вообще завершать форму при закрытии процесса а при открытии чтобы она снова запускалась

Comment: @ВасилийКристов WMI и ссылка выше.

Comment: Здесь есть пример отслеживания запуска процесса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769179/240512 (для отслеживания завершения используется аналогичное событие __InstanceDeletionEvent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Производите запуск приложение через отдельное вами написанное приложение или пишите службу.
Используйте `Process.WaitForExit` оно ожидает прекращение работы процесса.

Comment: Спасибо) Подошло

Comment: @ВасилийКристов Хоть отметь тогда как верный ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Добавь обработчик события на Process.Exited. При закрытии процесса закрывай и форму. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Да процесс то человек не сам запускает...

Comment: Какая разница
Пишешь:
pname[0].Exited += new EventHandler(Мой_обработчик);

Comment: @D.Stark Процесс называется "gameWoT" это уж явно игра следовательно этот процесс в любом случае откроет человек

Comment: @Tivyram "человек" я имею ввиду автор

Comment: @ValeryLosev Разве можно так делать с объектом уже запущенного процесса? Не знал...

Comment: Процесс это такой же объект, как к примеру форма. Так же выделяется поток, и так же может быть добавлены обработчики на события.